# NuGet targeting x86, x64 and AnyCPU in one Package

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

Since I was spending way to much on time on the following question, I wanted to share my results with you:

NuGet allows to target quite a lot of different setups, but when it comes to some advanced stuff, It's documentation isn't great. There is also quite a lot of different stuff floating around but it's all a big mess.

So I was stuck with this: How do I include a x86, x64 and Any CPU build with different target versions in just a single package?

Answer (score 2):

There are two existing SO-answers regarding this. Both of them lack a few details.

It's actually quite simple. At least, if you've spend around 5 hours on this.

1. Your files need to be placed in `build\{target framework version}\{architecture}`
2. You'll need to add a `.props` file to include your lib's. This file should contain following content:

   ```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
      <ItemGroup>
          <Reference Include="MyDll">
              <HintPath>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)$(Platform)\MyDll.dll</HintPath>
          </Reference>
       </ItemGroup>
    </Project>
   ```

   **make sure to replace the `MyDll` with your package and .dll name!***

   It has to be saved in every `build/{target framework version}` folder and has to use the name `MyDll.props`. Its final path should look something like this: `build/net452/MyDll.props`. You'll need to place it in every `build/{target framework version}` directory. This needs to be done so that NuGet stops being annoying and to get it to include our `.props` file. Sadly, it's not possible to include it only once in the `build/` folder (In theory, yes! In practice, it doesn't work).
3. If you want to get rid of the warning `WARNUNG: NU5127: This package does not contain a lib/ or ref/ folder, and will therefore be treated as compatible for all frameworks. Since framework specific files were found under the build/ directory for net452, consider creating the following empty files to correctly narrow the compatibility of the package: -lib/net452/_._`, You'll need to add an empty file with the name `_._` in every `lib\{target framework version}` directory.

### Final structure:

Your assembled NuGet package should look like this:

```
{root}/
  build/
    net452/
      MyDll.props
      AnyCPU/
        MyDll.dll
        MyDll.xml
        MyDll.pdb
      x86/
        MyDll.dll
        MyDll.xml
        MyDll.pdb
      x64/
        MyDll.dll
        MyDll.xml
        MyDll.pdb            
    netstandard2.1/
      MyDll.props
      AnyCPU/
        ...
      .../
  lib/
    net452/
      _._
    netstandard2.1/
      _._
```

### Example `.nuspec`

```xml
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata minClientVersion="3.2">
        ...
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <!-- .NETFramework 4.5.2 -->
        <file src="LSDOTNETCORE.props" target="build\net452" />
        <file src="_._" target="lib\net452" />
    
        <file src="Build\AnyCPU\Release\net452\LSDOTNETCORE.dll" target="build\net452\AnyCPU" />
        <file src="Build\AnyCPU\Release\net452\LSDOTNETCORE.xml" target="build\net452\AnyCPU" />
        <file src="Build\AnyCPU\Release\net452\LSDOTNETCORE.pdb" target="build\net452\AnyCPU" />    
        
        <file src="Build\x86\Release\net452\LSDOTNETCORE.dll" target="build\net452\x86" />
        <file src="Build\x86\Release\net452\LSDOTNETCORE.xml" target="build\net452\x86" />
        <file src="Build\x86\Release\net452\LSDOTNETCORE.pdb" target="build\net452\x86" />
        
        <file src="Build\x64\Release\net452\LSDOTNETCORE.dll" target="build\net452\x64" />
        <file src="Build\x64\Release\net452\LSDOTNETCORE.xml" target="build\net452\x64" />
        <file src="Build\x64\Release\net452\LSDOTNETCORE.pdb" target="build\net452\x64" />  
        
        <!-- .NET-Standard -->
        <file src="LSDOTNETCORE.props" target="build\netstandard2.1" />
        <file src="_._" target="lib\netstandard2.1" />
    
        <file src="Build\AnyCPU\Release\netstandard2.1\LSDOTNETCORE.dll" target="build\netstandard2.1\AnyCPU" />
        <file src="Build\AnyCPU\Release\netstandard2.1\LSDOTNETCORE.xml" target="build\netstandard2.1\AnyCPU" />
        <file src="Build\AnyCPU\Release\netstandard2.1\LSDOTNETCORE.pdb" target="build\netstandard2.1\AnyCPU" />    
        
        <file src="Build\x86\Release\netstandard2.1\LSDOTNETCORE.dll" target="build\netstandard2.1\x86" />
        <file src="Build\x86\Release\netstandard2.1\LSDOTNETCORE.xml" target="build\netstandard2.1\x86" />
        <file src="Build\x86\Release\netstandard2.1\LSDOTNETCORE.pdb" target="build\netstandard2.1\x86" />
        
        <file src="Build\x64\Release\netstandard2.1\LSDOTNETCORE.dll" target="build\netstandard2.1\x64" />
        <file src="Build\x64\Release\netstandard2.1\LSDOTNETCORE.xml" target="build\netstandard2.1\x64" />
        <file src="Build\x64\Release\netstandard2.1\LSDOTNETCORE.pdb" target="build\netstandard2.1\x64" />      
    </files>
</package>
```